# Is it possible to convert 4-pin floppy to SATA power?

Tags: electrical-power, sata, power-supply-unit, adapter, floppy

I just bought a server and realized that it had power for all my drive bays, but not for the internal SSD I bought for it. It does, however, have 2 free 4-pin floppy power connectors:

[image: 4-pin floppy power connector]

Is it possible to convert these to a SATA power connector using an adapter?

I have searched around for a while, and I can find a *lot* of SATA to 4-pin floppy (the wrong way around), but after a while I found this adapter on ebay:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/4-Pin-Floppy-FDD-Male-to-15-Pin-SATA-Female-Power-Adapter-Convertor-Cable-MX714-/371294563755

[image: 4-Pin Floppy FDD Male to 15-Pin SATA Female Power Adapter Convertor Cable MX714]

Is this legit? Will this work to power an SSD? The feedback on ebay seems overly positive and smells fishy, so I'm not convinced.

---

<sub>I feel weird linking to a product in a Serverfault question, but it was very relevant. If this is against the rules please remove the link</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is legit. All of these adapters use +5V or +12V pins with some earthing.

The adapter what you want to buy does only the physical conversion, because no electrical conversion is needed.

You could even convert them manually, by simply cutting a SATA power extension cable and soldering (or using terminal blocks).

Comment: You prefixed your answer with "the good thing:" - is there a downside? :D

Comment: @Hubro First I've understood your question so, that not the number of the power connectors are too low from your power, rather its power can't handle all your disks. Thus, my answer had been like so: "Yes, you can do this, and it will work, but it still wouldn't solve your power problem".

Comment: My problem is just a lack of connectors, sorry for wording it poorly :) an adapter will probably solve my problem

Comment: Just a follow-up, I ordered one of these (though not the one from ebay) and it's working. I now have the ability to put 2 extra internal SSDs into my server :)